# CMake - User libraries

Tags: cmake

Let's suppose I have a project organized as follows:

```
Proj/src
Proj/src/library_a
Proj/src/library_b
Proj/src/executable
```

What I would like to do is to collect the names of the libraries contained in `src/library_a` and `src/library_b` in a variable **Proj_LIBS** to be propagated up to the root of the CMake tree.

In the file `src/library_a/CMakeLists.txt`, I add all of the names of the targets to the variable **Proj_LIBS**, then I use this variable in the CMakeLists.txt file in folder `src/executable`.

The `Proj/src/library_a/CMakeLists.txt` is

```
add_library(A1 A1.cpp)
add_library(A2 A2.cpp)
SET(Curr_LIBS "${Proj_LIBS} A1 A2")
SET(Proj_LIBS ${Curr_LIBS} PARENT_SCOPE)
```

When I try to produce the executable with `Proj/src/executable/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_executable(exe1 exe1.cpp)
target_link_libraries(exe1 ${Proj_LIBS})
```

the names in **Proj_LIBS** are interpreted as library names, i.e, the compilation command prepared by CMake is:

```
gcc exe1.cpp -l A1 -l A2 -o exe1
```

and are not considered as dependencies as they are if I write the following lines in `Proj/src/executable/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_executable(exe1 exe1.cpp)
target_link_libraries(exe1 A1 A2)
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet the problem is using string instead of a list. Try this:

```
SET(Curr_LIBS "${Proj_LIBS};A1;A2")
SET(Proj_LIBS ${Curr_LIBS} PARENT_SCOPE)
```